# "Connection was not closed. Connection's current State was open"- Ms Access Visual Basic- Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, logging, ms-access-2010

My connection between my project and my Ms Access 2010 Database seems to be right at the moment of logging in with my project. However, After the first trial(if user and/or password are incorrect), when I try to log in again, the error is given. It says "Connection was not closed. Connection's current State was open". I just have found possible solutions for MySql service, but I'm using Ms Access database. The code where the error seems to be given is the following. Any suggestions?, please:

```
 Public Function Validation()


        da.Fill(dt)
        connection.Open()
        For Each DataRow In dt.Rows
            If txtUser.Text = DataRow.Item(0) And txtPassword.Text = DataRow(1) Then
                If cmbAccountType.Text = DataRow(2) Then
                    connection.Close()
                    Return True
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Return False
    End Function
```

Comment: This is because of your `if` statements. Take a pen and paper, and work through the logic with some data. Don't store passwords in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you opening the connection in the first place? You're not using it between the `Open` and `Close` calls so what's the point? The `Fill` method will automatically open the connection if it's currently closed and then it will automatically close it again if it opened it, i.e. `Fill` and `Update` will open the connection if necessary and then leave it in its original state afterwards. Get rid of both the `Open` and `Close` calls.

Comment: Thanks!, thinking about what you said about that Fill method automatically opens the connection, I just deleted the connection.Open() line and It worked. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, Function's in vb.net require a DataType. I have no idea what `da.Fill(dt)` is doing in this function. If you didn't have an open connection you wouldn't be able to fill anything but then on the next line you open some unknown connection from somewhere.

OleDb pays no attention to the names of parameters. The position of the parameters in the sql string must match the order that the parameters are added to the parameters collection.

Here is one approach.

```
Private ConnStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Validation(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text, cmbAccountType.Text) Then
        'Do something
    End If
End Sub

Public Function Validation(UName As String, PWord As String, Type As String) As Boolean
    Dim Count As Integer
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConnStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Count(*) From SomeTable Where User = @User And Password = @Password And AccountType = @Type;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = UName
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = PWord
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Type
        cn.Open()
        Count = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    If Count > 0 Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

Of course you should **NEVER** store passwords as plain text.

Comment: Actually, the code is for OleDB not ODBC but point taken. Answer is edited.